# Date string to datetime SQL Server for a dash-delimited format

Tags: sql-server, date-conversion

How do you convert a string like `2015-10-08 19:56:30.0` to a `datetime` in SQL Server without having to change languages?

Comment: So you want something like SELECT CAST('2015-10-08 19:56:30.0' AS DATETIME) ?

Comment: For reasons that I don't know this doesn't work on my server

Comment: What is the sql server version? and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: you are not using any column value from a table and tried running the code I have pasted?

Comment: I am using a column value

Comment: May be some of the values in the column are not in the same format as you have posted here. You can try what Ruhaan has posted. Does it work?

Comment: What is the type of your column? I am less interested in VARCHAR/NVARHCAR and more interested in the size.

Comment: What about `CONVERT(datetime, @yourDateString, 120)` or `CONVERT(datetime, @yourDateString, 121)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you, I have tried this.

```
Declare @Time as nvarchar(25)
Set @Time = '2015-10-08 19:56:30.0'
Select Cast(@Time As DateTime);
```

Comment: You're basically just cutting off the time portion by assigning the string to a variable that's too short to handle the whole string....